# Get the current VPC from CLI within the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

How is it possible to display the current VPC from the CLI within a running Linux (Debian) EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but using the [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) not the cli:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$( ip address show dev eth0 | grep ether | awk ' { print $2  } ' )/vpc-id
```

If your interface isn't named `eth0` update appropriately.